# Java arraylist addAll with generic type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a java class

```
public class PointCloud<T extends Point>
{
    protected ArrayList<T > points = null;

    public ArrayList<T> getPoints()
    {
        return points;
    }

    public void addPoints(ArrayList<T> arrayList)
    {
         this.points.addAll(arrayList);
    }

     public static PointCloud<? extends Point> combine(ArrayList<PointCloud<? extends Point>> pcList)
    {
        PointCloud<? extends Point> combinated_pc = new PointCloud<>();

        for(PointCloud<? extends Point> pc: pcList)
        {
            combinated_pc.addPoints(pc.getPoints());
        }

        return combinated_pc;
    }
}
```

My java error is :

> The method `addPoints(ArrayList < capture#8-of ? extends Point>)` in the
>   type `PointCloud<capture#8-of ? extends Point>` is not applicable for
>   the arguments (`ArrayList < capture#9-of ? extends Point>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to specify the proper generic type in order use the `addPoints` method.

Change your combine with following..

```
public static <P extends Point>  PointCloud<P> combine(ArrayList<PointCloud<P>> pcList) { 
    PointCloud<P> combinated_pc = new PointCloud<>(); 
    for(PointCloud<P> pc: pcList) { 
        combinated_pc.addPoints(pc.getPoints()); 
    } 
    return combinated_pc;
}
```

If you are interested in combining different kind of objects, you have modify the `addPoints` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem here is that the method is static, therefore T is not possible .

Comment: @Morkhitu actually you don't get it. The generic type T is applied because it is static. Look closely.. T is not return type. Return type is `PointCloud<T>`. You need to learn how to use generics on static methods.

Comment: @Morkhitu I have edited my answer to solve your misunderstanding with T used in class defination.

Comment: It's working and I have understood your solution, thanks a lot for your help.